# Is there a timeout for Windows Remote Desktop clipboard transfers and can it be modified?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, file-transfer, timeout

When I'm copying a large file over a slow remote desktop connection, every once in a while the transfer will fail silently.

Is this because there is some specified timeout for the transfer? If so, is there some registry key that can change this finite time period and/or specify an infinite value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this in the past as well. The workaround I used was log in as a domain administrator and mount the remote file system by typing "\name or IP\c$\folder" in a explorer window. You can also set up a shared folder to basically do the same thing.